# Rotating an object continously with OnMouseDown

Tags: c#, unity

I have a script that works but it does not do what I want it to do. My script makes an object rotate on when another is clicked. However, I want the object to continuously rotate until I click on the other object again. Right now when I click it rotates just a bit and stops.

Here is my script:

```
 public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed =50f;
    public GameObject target;

    public void OnMouseDown(){
       target.transform.Rotate (new Vector3(0, Time.deltaTime, 0) * speed);
    }
 }
```

How can I make the object rotate continuously until I click it again?

Answer (score 2):

Don't Rotate() in OnMouseDown(). Instead, have OnMouseDown() set an isRotating boolean value and then Rotate() in Update(). Something like:

```
bool isRotating;
void Update() {
  if (isRotating) {
    target.transform.Rotate(etc);
  }
}
void OnMouseDown() {
  isRotating != isRotating;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rotate will rotate it once by the amount specified. You must rotate it yourself every frame.

```
public float rotationSpeed = 50f;
public GameObject target;
private bool rotate = false;

void OnMouseDown() {
    rotate = !rotate; //this line toggles the bool "rotate" every time the object is clicked
}

void Update() {
    if(rotate) {
        target.transform.Rotate (new Vector3(0, Time.deltaTime, 0) * rotationSpeed );
    }
}
```

Comment: This question was asked on both SO and here. The duplicate was migrated here and merged.